# How to add IP filter in elastic search using X-Pack, without adding user authentication?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-x-pack, xpack

As soon as I remove `xpack.security.enabled: false` from `elasticsearch.yml` I start getting Username and Password authentication window, but if I have `xpack.security.enabled: false` I cannot add IP filter. How do I fix this?

I also tried adding

`xpack.security.audit.enabled: false
xpack.security.http.filter.enabled: true`

but it did not help

Comment: do you have both an xpack.security.transport.filter.deny and xpack.security.transport.filter.allow defined?